# run background loop or callbacks concurrently with qt C++ application?

Tags: c++, qt, callback, robotics

I'm writing a qt5 application in C++ to control my robotic contraption. I'm using a Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu 18.04 to accomplish this. The program will never run on anything but Linux. I'm not too familiar with qt, but it seems like the common way to run a qt application is by returning

```
int QApplication::exec()
```

in the main function. However, I need to run non-GUI-related code concurrently. For example, I need a callback to be executed every time my encoders change state. This callback has nothing to do with user input or the GUI. How can I make the main function receptive to the callback while it is running the qt application window at the same time?

The documentation says:

```
To make your application perform idle processing, i.e., executing a special function whenever
there are no pending events, use a QTimer with 0 timeout. More advanced idle processing schemes 
can be achieved using processEvents().
```

I don't really understand how either of these methods are applicable to my situation. Should either of these schemes be used, or should I use another technique? A simple example would help me a lot.

Edit: I'm adding this due to the comments below:

I'd rather not sample in intervals, because it would most likely miss some changes in state completely. I'm reading the data output from an AM26C32 chip via input on my gpio pins of the Pi. Essentially, every change in state needs to execute a callback. Since there are 40,000 states per motor revolution, I cannot have periodic checks -- the callbacks need to be executed immediately. The encoders (sensors) are incremental and not absolute. Also, I'm using the pigpio library for gpio handling.

Edit 2: After a bit more reading, I think I'll need to use QThread with event loops. The Raspberry Pi 3B+ has 4 cores; if I run the GUI on one thread, and each (of 2) encoder on another thread, this may work. Does anyone have experience with this? Am I on the right track here?

Comment: You could use a [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html), or you could start concurrent threads for this ([`QThread`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html)). I prefer `QTimer` if possible. (Threads introduce more effort to get them stable and free of sporadic issues due to their "natural" non-determinism.)

Comment: A `QTimer` (interval configurable in milliseconds) performs a periodic callback of a signal handler. If you have to read data periodically it might be sufficient but two additional requirements have to be matched: 1) Reading may not block. 2) Reading may not last too long. It's important that signal handlers return to event loop ASAP. (While a signal is handled the event loop is blocked.) For a blocking read, I see no alternative than to do it in an extra thread.

Comment: How are you going to read the data out of your sensors?

Comment: I'd rather not use intervals, because it would most likely miss some changes in state completely. I'm reading the data output from an AM26C32 chip via input on my gpio pins of the Pi. Essentially, every change in state needs to execute a callback. Since there are 40,000 states per motor revolution, I cannot have periodic checks -- the callbacks need to be executed immediately. Edit: The encoders (sensors) are incremental and not absolute. Also, I'm using the pigpio library for gpio handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me this is more about the design of the program to handle events, probably realtime asyou are talking about robotic control

As callback in qt application thread => Execution blocked by GUI events

In background thread => Mostly free from interruption from GUI events, as you can have control on the priority. See: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html

IMO handling in a background thread is a better options. Even if you are using Qt you can still use other threading / timer implementation.

The Frequency Counter 1 example from pigpio is still applicable

If you need communication between the callbacks and GUI, you can use a wait-free queue (e.g. https://github.com/Taymindis/wfqueue ) to pass message between them, while not being blocked by the progress of GUI thread

At the end you have to ensure the GPIO callback is can be completed in each interval.

Comment: Thanks, I'd vote you up, but I lack the rep. I'll probably accept your answer though soon. Qt has a QThread class, and I'll probably use that. I would base the logic on the separate thread on pigpio's encoder.cpp. As far as I can tell though, it is not threadsafe. Can I just make another identical class2 which does the same thing for the second encoder? Would that solve the threadsafe problem?

Comment: @madscientist Threadsafety is only an issue for things which are shared between threads. Using something in a `QThread` exclusively is safe as well as doing it in the main thread (i.e. without threading). It's only the interthread communication, you have to care about especially.

Comment: @Scheff thanks for the clarification. I suppose my only problem now is accessing gpio pins on separate threads as root. Any idea how I can do that without being superuser? The end-user is not going to be using the terminal, which is the whole reason I'm writing a GUI.

Comment: @madscientist I'm a bit weak about the permission management of *ix OSes. I roughly remember on something like [effective UID/GID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier). Sloppy said: If necessary you should provide the root rights to your application. I don't believe that a single thread may have a different permissions from the parent process. (But I might be unaware of a specific OS feature.)

Comment: @Scheff I'll give that a shot, though I'm not too sure how to elevate permission of a process.

Comment: @madscientist For this, SU is good for. ;-) [SU: Could a user space process start a root sub-process?](https://superuser.com/a/822964). Found it by [google "root permissions for user process"](https://www.google.com/search?q=root+permissions+for+user+process). If I got it right you just have to set the owner and permissions correctly for your application (after build) and then the effective UID/GID should be sufficient.

Comment: @Scheff this is not possible with Qt, unfortunately -- apparently it is some sort of security risk which is unsupported by both Qt and GTK+. I'm really stumped here.

Comment: @madscientist If you want a sudo equivalent in GUI you can try https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_get_applications_running_with_root_privileges